# Delete postman cache

Tags: postman

I use Postman extension to check out my RESTful APIs

I am trying to make a request to my "localhost", but it seems to have cached one of the query parameters.

I tried clearing cache of my chrome browser but this does not seem to work. I went to the extent of even changing the API resource name.

Has anyone come across such an issue?

Comment: Is the data cached or a setting in PM?

Comment: There is a setting where PM sends a header "no-cache" with every request. However it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Ah! How do you know it isn't working? Is the response data stale? Can you inspect the headers in the API?

Comment: Yes, it's a stale response. Even if i give wrong parameters (and I know that cause I have developed that api), it returns a previously generated response with isn't correct.

Comment: We're seeing this now whilst debugging an issue with an API. We fixed it by by opening a new tab and trying again.

Comment: Is this issue resolved?.am too having same problem.only works wen opened in new tab else previous result appears.

Comment: Issue still exists.

Comment: As of 2018 the issue still exists.

Comment: Be sure to isolate your issue by running the same request using `curl`. See https://ec.haxx.se/http/http-post. 

If you are getting the same issue, then it's your codebase/ide not Postman.

Comment: This issue is still occurring. @JanacMeena on using `curl` it is returning the actual response. Rehitting the API in Postman returns the stale response.

Comment: @AdityaGrover try using the postman app instead of the chrome extension

Comment: @JanacMeena, I have long since stopped using the Chrome extension. I got a stale response when running the Collection Runner, but not when running the requests one by one in the Postman app.

Comment: Hmm. Is this question a duplicate of [Postman Collection Runner runs stale request.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65903849)? That other question actually has an accepted answer, contrary to this question.

Comment: its 2021, the issue still exist.

Answer (score 11):

`Cache-Control` request header can be used but one thing to clarify

`no-cache` does not mean do not cache. In fact, it means on every HTTP request it "revalidate with server" before using any cached response. If the server says that the resource is still valid then the cache will still use the cached version.

while `no-store` is effectively asking to not cache at all and is intended not to to store anything in the cache.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution above and it didn't work for me. What worked was restart the application. I'm using eclipse and running a spring boot application.

In case someone is using the same environment and facing the same problem it may help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Postman App rather than the extension because with postman app you can do lot more cool things like you can use the console to debug your APIs, create/delete cookies and cache with excellent GUI.

Comment: This response is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

I came across same situation where the request are cached in Postman. I deleted JSESSIONID cookie from Cookies section on PM rather closing the PM app, it solved my problem (means - the call reached to my localhost app) and got accurate response. Please try it if someone needs this solution.

Answer (score -2):

I usually just request the data on a **chrome incognito tab/firefox private tab** and I guess that this just resets the cache and then it appears on my Postman app.

(I would recommend using the **Postman app** instead of the website as it has many more features!)